# excel crashes between end with and for loop?

Tags: excel, vba, crash

Adding a row randomly crashes my excel.

- Crashes can happen at `end with` or `for rij = 4 to lastRow`.
- Debugging very fast through the lines makes the program crash faster compared to taking 30 seconds of pause between the lines.
- I have the exact same code in a different module and it does work there.
- lastrow has the value 5 when I debug it, so the problem can't be `Rij > lastRow`

**code:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim IngevuldeCellen As Integer
Dim Ingevuld As Integer
Dim Rij As Integer
Dim tbl As Object
Dim AantalRijen As Integer
Dim laatsteRij As Long

Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     'Als laatste rij 6 ingevulde velden heeft doe dit
    lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    IngevuldeCellen = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B" & lastRow & ":G" & lastRow))
    If IngevuldeCellen >= 4 Then
        Call Module3.AddRowToBottom
        Range("F1:F" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 148, 0)
        Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 148, 0)

    ElseIf IngevuldeCellen < 4 Then
    Range("A" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Range("F" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
    
    
    Ingevuld = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H6:O18"))
    If Ingevuld >= 10 Then
        With Sheets("Ruimtelijst")
            lastRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        For Rij = 4 To lastRow
            If Not Intersect(Target, Blad3.ListObjects("tbl_" & Rij - 3).Range) Is Nothing Then
                'Zoek de laatste rij van de tabel op
                Set tbl = Blad3.ListObjects("tbl_" & Rij - 3)
                AantalRijen = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
                laatsteRij = tbl.Range.Cells(AantalRijen, "E").Row
                'Roept module
                Call Module3.AddRow(laatsteRij)
            End If
        Next Rij
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it is whole code, first paste all code lines please.

Comment: @Teamothy edited it. didn't expect you needed the whole code since it didn't had any issues there.

Comment: If it arbitrarily crashes you may have a corrupted compiled module, VBA is notorious for this. If so the only way to fix it that I am aware of is to create a new spreadsheet copy your code from the existing module, paste it into a new module in the new workbook, compile and save it.

Comment: I mean, it sort of is arbitrarily, it doesn't crash before the ```end with``` , the problem starts to occure between the ```end with``` and the ```for rij = 4 to lastrow``` lines because at the ```if not Intersect(Target, Blad3.ListObjects("tbl_" & Rij - 3).Range) Is Nothing Then``` line it works perfectly fine

Comment: Yes if it's arbritratily, even in one line (but that line isn't supposed to crash), try to fo what @Ethan said or try to clean the VBA project with [RibbonCommander](http://www.ribboncommander.com/index.php/download?source=esotericconsulting)

Comment: Specify worksheet in `lastRow`, this is the reason `lastRow` works randomly, also `Range` don't have specified on which worksheet etc.

Comment: oh forgot to mention. but what @Ethan said was the correct answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Teamothy I found out VBA modules can randomly get corrupted. I fixed this by copying all the code and pasting it in a new spreadsheet.